# Extjs 4.2 grid's state does not restore in Ext.window.Window view

Tags: extjs, grid, extjs4, extjs4.2

I use ExtJS version is 4.2. I'm trying to save the state of a grid, which is item of a window. When I close the window, state of the grid is saved in cookies, but it doesn't get restored when window is opened again. What did I miss?

This is my code:

```
Ext.onReady(function () {
    Ext.state.Manager.setProvider(Ext.create('Ext.state.CookieProvider'));

    Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        storeId: 'simpsonsStore',
        fields: ['name', 'email', 'phone'],
        data: {
            'items': [{
                'name': 'Lisa',
                "email": "lisa@simpsons.com",
                "phone": "555-111-1224"
            }, {
                'name': 'Bart',
                "email": "bart@simpsons.com",
                "phone": "555-222-1234"
            }, {
                'name': 'Homer',
                "email": "home@simpsons.com",
                "phone": "555-222-1244"
            }, {
                'name': 'Marge',
                "email": "marge@simpsons.com",
                "phone": "555-222-1254"
            }]
        },
        proxy: {
            type: 'memory',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'items'
            }
        }
    });

    Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
        items: [
            Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
                text: 'Click me',
                listeners: {
                    'click': function () {
                        var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
                            title: 'Simpsons',
                            store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
                            columns: [{
                                text: 'Name',
                                dataIndex: 'name'
                            }, {
                                text: 'Email',
                                dataIndex: 'email',
                                flex: 1
                            }, {
                                text: 'Phone',
                                dataIndex: 'phone'
                            }],

                            stateful: true,
                            stateId: 'some_state_id'
                        });

                        var win = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
                            title: 'Hello',
                            height: 200,
                            width: 900,
                            layout: 'fit',
                            items: grid
                        });

                        win.show();
                    }
                }
            })
        ]
    });
})
```

Here is the fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/20sf

Comment: Assign an `id` or `stateId` to each of the columns and the state information will be reapplied while creating the grid again.

Answer (score 1):

On every button click you create a new window with entirely new grid which just seems the same but for the state manager is absolutely another grid. You may check that by logging grid component through the ComponentManager and seeing a different grid id each time you click the button:

```
console.log(Ext.ComponentQuery.query('grid'));
```

To solve your problem I would recommend you to:

1. pull off the grid and window creation phase outside the button click
2. change window on close behaviour from destroy to hide by setting
       closeAction parameter to 'hide'
3. make your window component modal to prevent a user from another button click
       until the window is closed.

You may find corrected fiddle [here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/20sh) and code below:

```
Ext.onReady(function () {
    Ext.state.Manager.setProvider(Ext.create('Ext.state.CookieProvider'));

    var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        storeId: 'simpsonsStore',
        fields: ['name', 'email', 'phone'],
        data: {
            'items': [{
                'name': 'Lisa',
                "email": "lisa@simpsons.com",
                "phone": "555-111-1224"
            }, {
                'name': 'Bart',
                "email": "bart@simpsons.com",
                "phone": "555-222-1234"
            }, {
                'name': 'Homer',
                "email": "home@simpsons.com",
                "phone": "555-222-1244"
            }, {
                'name': 'Marge',
                "email": "marge@simpsons.com",
                "phone": "555-222-1254"
            }]
        },
        proxy: {
            type: 'memory',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'items'
            }
        }
    });

    var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        title: 'Simpsons',
        store: store,
        columns: [{
            text: 'Name',
            dataIndex: 'name'
        }, {
            text: 'Email',
            dataIndex: 'email',
            flex: 1
        }, {
            text: 'Phone',
            dataIndex: 'phone'
        }],

        stateful: true,
        stateId: 'some_state_id'
    });

    var win = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
        title: 'Hello',
        height: 200,
        width: 400,
        modal: true,
        layout: 'fit',
        closeAction: 'hide',
        items: grid
    });

    Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
        items: [
            Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
                text: 'Click me',
                listeners: {
                    'click': function () {
                        // console.log(Ext.ComponentQuery.query('grid'));
                        win.show();
                    }
                }
            })
        ]
    });
})
```

Comment: StateManager depends on [`stateId`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.state.Stateful-cfg-stateId) to relate a cached state object with the control being created. `id` is optional.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You solution is working. But using " closeAction: 'hide' " for windows does not suit me.